# backbone this.listenTo not running

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working with a backbone this.listenTo to check if the status is changing on my application from open to closed. However, it is just returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

**I know that the variables I am grabbing are correct**, I am using them in multiple other places and consoling them right above the function.

My console looks like this returning the correct status

```
console.log(this.app.get('Device').get('Status'));
```

and my listenTo looks like this

```
this.listenTo(this.app.get('Device'), "change:Status", function(event){
    console.log('changed');
});
```

I am sure it's just something stupid, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `TypeError` is from that `this.listenTo` call? What is `this` in this context? Are you sure that `this.app.get('Device')` is correct? You're `console.log` is checking `get('Session')` but you're really using `get('Device')`.

Comment: @muistooshort I am positive it is coming from the ListenTo. As soon as it is commented out the error goes away plus I have it in a function that triggers every five seconds and it's the only thing that keeps firing every five seconds. Yes, I am sure my variables are correct, I am using them in multiple other places and the console.log is just a typo. I was in the wrong file when copy and pasted apparently.

Comment: @muistooshort this is referring to the window, but I also tried this.app and then it just skips the function silently. From what I've been reading everyone says to just use this.

Comment: (1) You only want to call `listenTo` once, not every 5s. (2) If this stuff is being called by `setTimeout` or `setInterval` then `this` will be `window`. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @muistooshort No matter where I put the function its either returning the error or skipping it silently. I do need to keep checking if the status changes though so I can make sure to close down the website if it is closing time and I'm at the point of trying anything under the sun. iF I take it out of the set Interval it only hit it once on page load and then just skips it. I don't really know what other context you need...?

Comment: @muistooshort Also, if I move the listenTo outside of the interval then the this.app becomes null because when the page first loads the varable is not there and it does not hit that function again.

Comment: But each time you call `this.listenTo`, you're adding another listener. You only need to `listenTo` once and then the thing will call the listener when the `Status` attribute changes. If you can provide a self-contained demo of what you're doing I can walk you through it.

Comment: But, it's not calling it every time variable changes and it's only calling it once when this.app does not exist yet. It blows up my entire application. I think this may be a little too complicated to put in a jsFiddle with the backbone, knockout, knockback and plus I can only share snippets of my code according to my companies policy.

Comment: I had a similar `listenTo` issue recently in which the `.listenTo` was within `initialize` of `Backbone.View`, unable to figure out, I just changed it to `.on` and it worked